# Electron-Vue generate PDF files dynamically from JSON and download

Tags: json, vue.js, pdf, download, electron

Using electron with vuejs I want to be able to create on the flow dynamic PDF files for download.

Practically the user story looks as it follows: 
- users clicks on download PDF button and data gets fetched as JSON and converted to a PDF file and pushed to download popup window.

What are the best practices in this case?

I read about `html-pdf` nodejs library but I can not really decide if would meet my case. I do not know how would I generate a html file on the flow with the JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

You can load a PDF file and add text where ever you want.